# Recommendations on Operations Statistics/Analytics Approaches/Materials

Tags: modeling, reference-request, statistics

I'm an operations data analyst. I was wondering if I can get recommendations on books/videos on statistical models specific to optimizing business operations through analytics and statistical modeling.

An example of a problem I am trying to solve is trying to understand if the variance in case volume divided by customer population and intersected over time are statistically significant. E.g. if I were to compare the previous week's performance with this week's performance. The objective here is to understand if the delta between the two weeks is significant. I am not necessarily trying to take into account all of the previous weeks and using linear regression to find future values.

Comment: looks like you are looking for ANOVA. You can find many videos on youtube. e.g.: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITf4vHhyGpc

Comment: [Moving Average Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving-average_model) [Autoregressive Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model)